# Bands With Eponymous Album and Song

Tags: song-title, album-title

The band ***Black Sabbath***'s first album is called *Black Sabbath* and was released in 1970. The leading track on that album is also called "Black Sabbath." Does anybody know of any other manifestation of this phenomenon?

> Are there other examples of bands, whose name appears as both the
>   title of one of their albums and as a song within that album?

Comment: This question should probably have a single answer that's edited to cover the full list, probably marked as community-wiki so that any user can easily edit it to keep it updated - rather than a million individual answers, each mentioning a single band.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first answer I can think of is **Iron Maiden's [*Iron Maiden*](https://youtu.be/1c366GqSP8Y?t=2231)** in the album *Iron Maiden* in 1980 so after *Black Sabbath* in 1970.

Answer (score 5):

Bad Company did the same on their 1974 eponymous album. Can’t think of any others at the moment....

...After looking through my music a second time, I found a few ‘almosts’: Gentle Giant has a song just called Giant on their 1970 eponymous album, and The Monkees put the theme to their TV show of the same name on their 1966 eponymous album, which may or may not ‘count’ depending on sensibilities.

Answer (score 4):

One such example is [Motörhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot%C3%B6rhead_(album)) (though the song title is sometimes written without an Umlaut.)

Comment: Although the song 'motorhead' was by Hawkwind - written by Lemmy though . . .

Comment: It was recorded by Motörhead on the s/t album though, and they often played it live. Was it ever actually recorded by Hawkwind?

Comment: In July 1981 "Motorhead" was released as the A-side to a 7" and 12" single on the Flicknife label
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorhead_(song)
I still think 'motorhead' is a valid answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

I know of [Valkeat](https://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Valkeat/3540422316), a folk metal band from Finland. They released their debut album, named [Valkeat](https://www.metal-archives.com/albums/Valkeat/Valkeat/629145), in 2017 and one of the songs in this album is called [Valkeat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cxi_L0dHzJ8).

Answer (score 3):

You know the three obvious ones: *Bad Company*, *Black Sabbath*, *Iron Maiden*

I've been at this question for a long time. I often ask it around parties, camp fires, or when people look bored. Another four I know of because I own the vinyl albums:

1 - *Autosalvage*- from NYC Around 1966 (hard record to find too!)

2 - *Lucifer's Friend* - German band from around 1970, whose members are also involved with another outfit/ project called Electric Food. Which is also around 1970. These guys would tour, record, and "Be" with these bands all at the same time. Talk about commitment!  What a workload.

3 - *Universe*- A British band from Wales in 1970. These guys used to be called Spoonfull in the '60s. An original vinyl record of this band goes for about $1000. Hell, even the repressed vinyl I bought cost over $100.

4 - *Sea Train* - was the aftermath of the blues project. Say....'69-'70.

Most of my research is off the vinyl album covers and liner notes with the record.  And to fill in some of the blanks, used Discogs, but only for the corrections and a few dates.

Answer (score 3):

The closing track ‘The Good, the Bad & the Queen’, on the 2007 album ‘The Good, the Bad & the Queen’ by Damon Albarn led supergroup ‘The Good, the Bad & the Queen’.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_%26_the_Queen_(album))

Answer (score 2):

Also in 1970 Dutch prog band Focus released their debut studio album 'In and Out of Focus' (earlier released as 'Focus Plays Focus'), the first and last tracks of which were instrumental and vocal versions of a track called 'Focus'.

(They later had umpteen albums with 'Focus' in the title somewhere plus a single and an album called 'Hocus Pocus'.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is the middle that is different.

Popular once upon a time famous album [The First of a Million Kisses](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_of_a_Million_Kisses) by [Fairground Attraction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairground_Attraction) features the track *Fairground Attraction*.

Comment: Yeah, the same goes for the song "Talk Talk" on the debut album "The Party's Over" by the band Talk Talk.

Answer (score 1):

Blackfield with their track Blackfield on their debut album, Blackfield.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Jewels by Run the Jewels off of Run the Jewels
Hellyeah by Hellyeah off of Hellyeah